# How can the local feature size become arbitrarily small?

Tags: computational-geometry

I am stuck at the following exericse:

> Let $\rho$ denote the local feature size. Draw an example where the curve C contains the line segment from $(-1, 0)$ to $(1, 0)$, but where $\rho( (0,0) )$ is arbitrarily small.

Here are the definitions that I heard in class:

> Let $C$ be a smooth closed curve in the plane, and let $x$ be a
> point of $C$. The local feature size $\rho(x)$ of x is the shortest distance from $x$ to the medial axis of C. (The medial axis $M(C)$ of a closed smooth curve $C$ is the locus of the centers of disks that touch $C$ at two or more distinct points.)

I do not understand how it should be possible for the local feature size to become arbitrarily small, since we are looking at *smooth* plane curves. I have tried to draw some examples, but the ones I found were always non-smooth, like the one below. (The image comes from [Wikipedia's article on cusps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)).)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have suspected, it is impossible for a **simple** smooth closed curve to contain the line segment from (−1,0) to (1,0) such that its local feature size at $(0,0)$ is arbitrarily small.

On other hand, it is easy to draw a self-intersecting smooth curve with that property. Here is an example.

[image]

In fact, for every smooth curve that contains the line segment from (−1,0) to (1,0) and intersects itself at $(0,0)$, its local feature size at $(0,0)$ will be arbitrarily small.